# stop pulling a docker image from the public docker-hub registry

Tags: docker-registry

Is there any way to stop pulling a docker image from the public docker-hub registry while building image locally. 
Note: We are maintaining a private registry that contains all the images. Only and only docker-engine should search for an image from the private registry and not from the public registry.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot change the default registry (see [this](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/7203)). You have to specify which registry to use like this:

```
docker pull myprivatereg:port/library/image
```

Or, in a Dockerfile:

```
FROM myprivatereg:port/library/image
```

(This question was also asked in [StackOverlow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33054369/how-to-change-the-default-docker-registry-from-docker-io-to-my-private-registry)).